# How to get attributes of a link?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I need to get attributes from a hyperlink like:

```
<a href="/groups/49882348/edit#" id="toleft" w_command="add_holiday" w_controller="groups" w_id="49882348" w_type="POST">&lt;&lt;</a>
```

and I want to get w_command, what do I have to do in Javascript?
I tried the following:

```
var lin = document.getElementById("#toleft");
var w_controller = lin.attr("w_controller");
```

But this won't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var lin = document.getElementById("toleft");
var w_controller = lin.getAttribute("w_controller");
alert(w_controller);
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/DeWX4/)**

Answer (score 2):

`@Kiranramchandran` got it for javascript, but for JQuery you'll be able to do this:

```
var lin = $("#toleft");
var w_controller = lin.attr("w_controller");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U88UW/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Both of your answers work, but, as @Kiranramchandran's answer is less specific, I'll flag his as the answer, because it works, either you use jquery or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery:

```
console.log($('#toleft')[0].attributes['w_controller']);
```